# Can't parse Date with DateTimeFormat

Tags: json, parsing, datetime-format

I can't get a string to be parsed by a DateTimeFormat format. Here is the input string : 
`Thu Apr 07 00:00:00 EDT 2011`

and my format:
`DateTimeFormat.getFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss vvv yyyy");`

I've read that this is the correct format string, but for me it's not parsing correctly. Here is the code:

```
public class YcDateColumn extends TextColumn<JSONObject> {

    DateTimeFormat fmtC = DateTimeFormat.getFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
    DateTimeFormat fmtB = DateTimeFormat.getFormat("MMM dd, yyyy hh:mm:ss a");
    DateTimeFormat fmtA = DateTimeFormat.getFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss vvv yyyy");


    private String key = null;
    private String def = null;

    public YcDateColumn(String aKey, String aDefault) {
        super();
        key = aKey;
        def = aDefault;
    }

    public YcDateColumn(String aKey) {
        this(aKey, null);
    }

    @Override
    public String getValue(JSONObject aObj) {
            System.out.println("YcDateColumn - object= " + aObj);
        JSONValue mVal = aObj.get(key);
        if (mVal == null)
            return def;
        System.out.println("YcDateColumn -  about to parse string: " + mVal.isString().stringValue());
        return fmtC.format(fmtA.parse(mVal.isString().stringValue()));
    }

}
```

The last System.out prints this text (the string to parse): `YcDateColumn -  about to parse string: Thu Apr 07 00:00:00 EDT 2011`

What am I missing!? Thanks for the help!

-Eric

Comment: I don't this `zzz` will correctly match the timezone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

zzz in your format string requires a number (the offset). Your date has EDT. You will need to use v for the timezone.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I have no doubt that was 1 error in my code, but it still isn't working. I have updated the question to include your fix though

Comment: I ended up figuring out how to prevent the date from going into this format at all. So now it works, using a different source string (and obviously parsing pattern).

Comment: excellent, can you either mark my answer as answer, or create an answer describing your fix and mark that as answered?